# Rewrite first level subfolders that do not have trailing slash htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm wondering how I can rewrite first level sub folders which do not have a trailing slash to a php file using mod rewrite.

For example

```
/test      -> rewrites to file.php?id=test
/test/     -> trailing slash so it follows through as normal to /test/
/test/test -> second level sub folder so it follows through as normal to /test/test
/          -> homepage needs to follow through as usual to index.php
```

Was trying to think of a rule to do this in 1 line. For the above example, test is just an example and the rule should rewrite any string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this by disabling mod_dir's `DirectorySlash`. There's very good reasons for requiring trailing slashes on directories because otherwise the entire contents can be viewable even if there's an index file. So this is incredible risky.

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# attempt to add trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+[^/])$ /$1/$2/ [L,R]

# route to file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /file.php?id=$1 [L]
```